# How to typeset the *same* table of contents twice: once with depth 0, and then with depth 1

Tags: table-of-contents

Suppose a book has only 4 chapters. Suppose each chapter has a ridiculously large number of sections, say, 100.  A table of contents with depth=0 for this book will take only 1 page, whereas a table of contents with depth=1 will run to 20 pages.

For such a book, it would be great to have 2 consecutive tables of contents: the first would refer to chapters only, and the second would break down chapters into sections.

How could I do this?

In the following example, the second TOC gets blank.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\tableofcontents

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
\section{a} \section{b} \section{c} \section{d} \section{e}
\chapter{Two}
\section{a} \section{b} \section{c} \section{d} \section{e}
\chapter{Three}
\section{a} \section{b} \section{c} \section{d} \section{e}
\chapter{Four}
\section{a} \section{b} \section{c} \section{d} \section{e}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

package `shorttoc`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\begin{document}
\shorttableofcontents{\contentsname}{0}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents



\chapter{One}
\section{a} \section{b} \section{c} \section{d} \section{e}
\chapter{Two}
\section{a} \section{b} \section{c} \section{d} \section{e}
\chapter{Three}
\section{a} \section{b} \section{c} \section{d} \section{e}
\chapter{Four}
\section{a} \section{b} \section{c} \section{d} \section{e}

\end{document}
```

you can use `\shorttoc{\contentsname}{0}`