# Toc with respect to parts and chapters

Tags: table-of-contents

Minitoc is really great when using it within various chapters.
But what should be used when a toc is required, which lists only parts and chapters? I called it abstracttoc to show the position where it should be applied.

e.g.

```
\begin{document} 
A few words initially. 
\abstracttoc % only parts and chapters 
And a few words.
\tableofcontents % as usual
\part{One} 
\chapter{A} 
a few words 
\section{SEC A} 
a few words
\section{SEC AA} 
a few words
\chapter{B} 
a few words 
\section{SEC B} 
a few words
\section{SEC BB} 
a few words
\part{Two} 
\chapter{Z} 
a few words 
\section{SEC ZZ} 
a few words
\section{SEC ZZZ} 
a few words   
\chapter{C} 
a few words 
\section{SEC CC}
a few words
\section{SEC CCC}
a few words
\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer is given here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240189/how-to-typeset-the-same-table-of-contents-twice-once-with-depth-0-and-then-w

Comment: @PietvanOostrum Thanks a lot - you could post it as answer.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment. Otherwise your question gets marked as unclear.